# Canot resolve package dependencies

Tags: 12.04, dependencies

Ive fresh installed ubuntu 12.04 and wanted to look for updates.
An error occurred and asked if i want to repair dependencies. So I did what it asked for but it failed again and again and again.
Same thing happens when i want to install software from repositories "sudo apt-get install ...".
Ive read that it can be solved by installing missing dependencies by "sudo apt-get install -f". But it failed with error again:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libqtcore4_4%3a4.8.1-0ubuntu4_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any suggestions what to do?

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

gave me:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libqtgui4:i386
 libqt4-sql:i386
 ia32-libs-multiarch:i386
 libqt4-declarative:i386
 libqt4-svg:i386
 libqt4-network:i386
 libqt4-sql-mysql:i386
 libqt4-script:i386
 libqt4-dbus:i386
 ia32-libs
 libqt4-opengl:i386
 libqtwebkit4:i386
 libqt4-designer:i386
 libqt4-scripttools:i386
 libqt4-qt3support:i386
 libqt4-xml:i386
 libqt4-test:i386
 libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386
```

Ive done:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install -f
```

still getting this error:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libqtcore4_4%3a4.8.1-0ubuntu4_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Have you used any PPAs?

Comment: try this: sudo dpkg --configure -a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean your cache and redownload the packages `sudo apt-get clean` `sudo apt-get autoclean`, then try with `sudo apt-get install -f` , I've been getting these errors too.

Comment: Still getting same error. (updated my first post)

Comment: Open nautilus with root permissions `gksu nautilus` navigate to the folder and delete the file then try again, and try with a different mirror.

Comment: How can i choose different mirror?

Comment: Open software properties `software-properties-gtk`

Comment: Ive changed the mirror to one of recommended locals and updated all i found. It looks great :)
Ty for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

Same here but with also the following output:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mysql-community-server : Depends: mysql-common (= 5.7.10-1ubuntu14.04) but 5.7.11-1ubuntu14.04 is to be installed
                      Depends: mysql-client (= 5.7.10-1ubuntu14.04)
mysql-server : Depends: mysql-community-server (= 5.7.11-1ubuntu14.04) but 5.7.10-1ubuntu14.04 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

The solution for me was:

```
sudo apt-get install -f mysql-community-server
```