# How to fix severe libqt4 package dependency problems?

Tags: 12.04

How can I fix my Software center? I can't update Ubuntu or anything without getting an error that items cannot be installed until the package catalog is repaired.
 Below is the errors I get. Please help I'm a noob Ubuntu.

```
installArchives() failed: dpkg: error processing libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 (--configure):
 libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1 cannot be configured because libqt4-xmlpatterns:amd64 is in a different version (4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2)
dpkg: error processing libqt4-xmlpatterns (--configure):
 libqt4-xmlpatterns:amd64 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 cannot be configured because libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 is in a different version (4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1)
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-declarative:i386:
 libqt4-declarative:i386 depends on libqt4-xmlpatterns (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Version of libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 on system is 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-declarative:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-declarative:
 libqt4-declarative depends on libqt4-xmlpatterns (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Package libqt4-xmlpatterns is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-declarative (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqtgui4:i386:
 libqtgui4:i386 depends on libqt4-declarative (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Package libqt4-declarative:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqtgui4:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqtgui4:
 libqtgui4 depends on libqt4-declarative (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Package libqt4-declarative is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqtgui4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-designer:
 libqt4-designer depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Package libqtgui4 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-designer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-designer:i386:
 libqt4-designer:i386 depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Package libqtgui4:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-designer:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-help:
 libqt4-help depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Package libqtgui4 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-help (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-opengl:
 libqt4-opengl depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Package libqtgui4 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-opengl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-opengl:i386:
 libqt4-opengl:i386 depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Package libqtgui4:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-opengl:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-qt3support:i386:
 libqt4-qt3support:i386 depends on libqt4-designer (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Package libqt4-designer:i386 is not configured yet.
 libqt4-qt3support:i386 depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Package libqtgui4:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-qt3support:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-scripttools:
 libqt4-scripttools depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Package libqtgui4 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-scripttools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-scripttools:i386:
 libqt4-scripttools:i386 depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Package libqtgui4:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-scripttools:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-svg:
 libqt4-svg depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Package libqtgui4 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-svg (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-svg:i386:
 libqt4-svg:i386 depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Package libqtgui4:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-svg:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386
 libqt4-xmlpatterns
 libqt4-declarative:i386
 libqt4-declarative
 libqtgui4:i386
 libqtgui4
 libqt4-designer
 libqt4-designer:i386
 libqt4-help
 libqt4-opengl
 libqt4-opengl:i386
 libqt4-qt3support:i386
 libqt4-scripttools
 libqt4-scripttools:i386
 libqt4-svg
 libqt4-svg:i386
Error in function: 
SystemError: E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-declarative:i386:
 libqt4-declarative:i386 depends on libqt4-xmlpatterns (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Version of libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 on system is 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-declarative:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: error processing libqt4-xmlpatterns (--configure):
 libqt4-xmlpatterns:amd64 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 cannot be configured because libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 is in a different version (4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1)
dpkg: error processing libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 (--configure):
 libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1 cannot be configured because libqt4-xmlpatterns:amd64 is in a different version (4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2)
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqtgui4:i386:
 libqtgui4:i386 depends on libqt4-declarative (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Package libqt4-declarative:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqtgui4:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-declarative:
 libqt4-declarative depends on libqt4-xmlpatterns (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Package libqt4-xmlpatterns is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-declarative (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-svg:i386:
 libqt4-svg:i386 depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Package libqtgui4:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-svg:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-opengl:i386:
 libqt4-opengl:i386 depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Package libqtgui4:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-opengl:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-designer:i386:
 libqt4-designer:i386 depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Package libqtgui4:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-designer:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-scripttools:i386:
 libqt4-scripttools:i386 depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Package libqtgui4:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-scripttools:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-qt3support:i386:
 libqt4-qt3support:i386 depends on libqt4-designer (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Package libqt4-designer:i386 is not configured yet.
 libqt4-qt3support:i386 depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Package libqtgui4:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-qt3support:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqtgui4:
 libqtgui4 depends on libqt4-declarative (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Package libqt4-declarative is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqtgui4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-svg:
 libqt4-svg depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Package libqtgui4 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-svg (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-opengl:
 libqt4-opengl depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Package libqtgui4 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-opengl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-designer:
 libqt4-designer depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Package libqtgui4 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-designer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-help:
 libqt4-help depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Package libqtgui4 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-help (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-scripttools:
 libqt4-scripttools depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Package libqtgui4 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-scripttools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Comment: Please show the terminal-output of `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with package dependencies in Qt4 library](http://askubuntu.com/questions/167464/problem-with-package-dependencies-in-qt4-library)

Answer (score 1):

From your logfiles it looks like a problem with libqt4-xmlpatterns
Please have a look here (if you have not yet done so): https://askubuntu.com/a/167933/83946
That question is about the same software package.

Basically, do the following in a terminal:

```
apt-get download libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386
apt-get download libqt4-xmlpatterns:amd64
sudo dpkg -i libqt4-xmlpatterns*.deb
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: in case dpkg can't install the packet, try passing --force-depend option